# What happened to the blog's podcast player?

Tags: support, blog, podcast

The Stack Exchange blog used to have an inline player for the podcast posts. For example, the [Podcast #41](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/01/podcast-41-neither-of-us-have-muscles/) post has this:

[image]

But that's missing from the [Podcast #42](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/02/podcast-42-2/?cb=1) post:

[image]

Is that some kind of bug, or was the player intentionally removed?

Comment: Someone forgot to pay the Soundcloud bill.

Comment: Just noticed it works from the Soundcloud website: https://soundcloud.com/stack-exchange/stack-exchange-podcast-42. So maybe someone just forgot to add the embed code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No bug or anything, just a forgetful blog post writer (that's me!).  It's been added now

Comment: Forgetful writer is forgiven! :)